# Why do I have godlike gist powers?

Tags: support, chat, onebox

I thought chat oneboxed gists. And in fact, it does. I oneboxed [gist #5363882](https://gist.github.com/5363882) some minutes ago.

Someone was surprised at that, and gave it a try—his link didn't get oneboxed.

And then the [Lounge<C++>](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) fell into [an endless series of posting gist links](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/robot-is-godlike), trying to steal the secret onebox fire from the gods.

Comment: The failed gists oneboxes are due to 403s (forbidden) responses from GitHub.

Comment: Maybe it uses 'klass' variable too.

Comment: The only instance I could find was'Myleene'

Comment: int main(){} // nothing is returned??

Comment: Use your power wisely!

Comment: Github is having some issues on their side...it made me login to view definitely public stuff earlier this morning.  This is affecting our API calls as well.

Comment: @Telkitty check out the file's extension. You mind will be blown.

Comment: @RMartinhoFernandes http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=humblebrag

Comment: @Pops "I am special. Better than you. Admit it." doesn't sounds like a very good show of humility.